# Speed up SQl Query using XML without namespace

Tags: sql, xml

Is there a way to speed this up?  There is no namespace.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 AS t1 WITH (nolock)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    table2 AS t2 WITH (nolock)
ON t1.term_uid = t2.term_uid
WHERE t1.code IN 
         ('305.1', 'Z72.0', 'F17.200') OR 
     t2.term_code
     ('(/Attributes/Attribute[@name="myName"]/text())[1]', 'varchar(20)') IN
         ('305.1', 'Z72.0', 'F17.200');
```

Comment: Pls. specify type of DB.

Comment: Please give some more details: How does your XML look like? Are there many different Attribute-nodes in there? Do you need this often? Do you ever need the "myName" -Attribute's value?

Comment: So sorry - the db is MS SQL 2008.  The xml for the field can be different for each row.  Below I've included two different rows data:

Comment: <Attributes xmlns=""><br />
          <Attribute name="AGE_INDICATOR">3</Attribute><br />
          <Attribute name="DSM_AXIS_III">1</Attribute>
          <Attribute name="GENDER_INDICATOR">M</Attribute>
          <Attribute name="ICD10CA_PREF">R76.8</Attribute>
          <Attribute name="ICD10CM_BILL_TYPE">1</Attribute>
          <Attribute name="ICD10CM_PREF">R97.2</Attribute>
          <Attribute name="ICD10WHO_PREF">R76.8</Attribute>
          <Attribute name="ICD9CM_BILL_TYPE">1</Attribute>
          <Attribute name="ICD9CM_PREF">790.93</Attribute>
        </Attributes>

Comment: <Attributes xmlns="">  
  <Attribute name="COMM_HHS_HCC">HHS_HCC082</Attribute>  
  <Attribute name="DSM_AXIS_I">1</Attribute>  
  <Attribute name="HCC_MODEL_CATEGORY_TEXT">Substance Abuse</Attribute>  
  <Attribute name="ICD10CM_BILL_TYPE">1</Attribute>  
  <Attribute name="ICD10CM_PREF">F19.20</Attribute>  
  <Attribute name="ICD10CM_SPECIFICITY">2</Attribute>  
  <Attribute name="ICD9CM_BILL_TYPE">1</Attribute>  
  <Attribute name="ICD9CM_HCC_MODEL_CAT">55</Attribute>  
  <Attribute name="ICD9CM_PREF">304.92</Attribute>     
</Attributes>

Comment: And, I will need to do this a bunch, and in derived queries.

Comment: Thx for the examples... I assume you are not always searching for `'305.1', 'Z72.0', 'F17.200'` ? Are you always searching for three parts? Are you always searching for the same Attribute (e.g. "ICD10CM_PREF") or do you search for *any* compliance with your search string(s) or do you search in several dedicated Attributes? This is still not enough to help you...